# Making a MadLib in Java - User Input Erroring

Tags: java, input

I am VERY new to Java and I'm trying to make a madlib that takes user input and inserts it into a sentence. So far, I'm not having much luck. When I run the program, it prompts me for the first input, but after that it errors out. Do you know why? I think it has something to do with data types (int, string, etc).

Bonus question: How would I make the inputs appear **bold** once inserted into the paragraph? Assuming I can get this code to work in the first place.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Madlib
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     int firstName, childAge, colorToy, typeToy;
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Enter someone's first name:");
     firstName = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Enter a child's age:");
     childAge = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Enter a color:");
     colorToy = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Enter a toy:");
     typeToy = input.nextInt();

     System.out.println("\"I am" + childAge + "years old, so that means I get to have the" + colorToy + typeToy + "!\" exclaimed the little girl.");
     System.out.println("\"Share with your sister,\"" + firstName + "grovelled, barely peering over their large, Sunday newspaper.");
   }
}
```

Comment: 1 - what do you mean by "madlib"? Definitely not the thing covered by the `madlib` question tag. 2 - making things **bold** depends on the output medium, there's no universal way of making things bold.

Comment: I assume that when you are asking for someone's first name, you don't expect an integer as input.  So, why the line `firstName = input.nextInt();`?

Comment: I'm new to coding so I'm just trying to figure out types and how Java handles them. As far as the madlib thing, it is a madlib as far as I've been taught. Being told to give input that is then inserted into a sentence. Is there another definition for "madlib"?

Comment: I ended up figuring this out on my own. Changed int to string. My brain was pretty fried yesterday, but at least I learned something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because

```
firstName, childAge, colorToy, typeToy
```

should all not supposed to be an integer. They are supposed to be String You should be doing

```
firstName = input.nextLine();
childAge = input.nextLine();
colorToy = input.nextLine();
typeToy = input.nextLine();
```

Also, this is not part of your question; however, when you do

```
System.out.println("\"I am " + childAge + " years old, so that means I get to have the " + colorToy + " " + typeToy + "!\" exclaimed the little girl.");
System.out.println("\"Share with your sister,\"" + " " + firstName + " grovelled, barely peering over their large, Sunday newspaper.");
```

It should look like that with spaces included in places that you didn't have them in. I hope this answered your question!